# SQL: Single VS multiple join tables

Tags: database-design, join

Let's say that we have the following tables:

- `user`
- `team`
- `meeting`

Both a `team` and a `meeting` can have multiple `users` (1-to-many relationship).

What is the best way to model this DB structure?

**Option 1:**

1 join table for the `team-user` and `meeting-user` relationships:

columns: `user_id`, `team_id`, `meeting_id`
example rows:
`1, 3, null`
`1, null, 4`

**Option 2:**

2 join tables, one for the `team-user` and one for the `meeting-user` relationship

columns table 1: `user_id`, `team_id`
example row: `1, 3`

columns table 2: `user_id`, `meeting_id`
example rows: `1, 4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2, `team-user` and `meeting-user` as separate tables. It'll give you more flexibility for more use cases, for example if not all `users` of the same `team` attend a specific `meeting`.

In option 1, you wouldn't be able to determine who all the `users` of that `team` are if such a case happened. With option 2, you would easily be able to see who all of the `users` of that `team` are, regardless of their attendance to a specific `meeting`.

Separate tables, different purposes, more flexibility, better design.